# GCM sending multiple message in one request

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've got following method in my CCS Server.

```
public static String createJsonMessage(JsonArray to, String messageId,
        Map<String, String> payload, String collapseKey, Long timeToLive,
        Boolean delayWhileIdle) {
    Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    message.put("to", to);
    if (collapseKey != null) {
        message.put("collapse_key", collapseKey);
    }
    if (timeToLive != null) {
        message.put("time_to_live", timeToLive);
    }
    if (delayWhileIdle != null && delayWhileIdle) {
        message.put("delay_while_idle", true);
    }
    message.put("message_id", messageId);
    message.put("data", payload);
    return JSONValue.toJSONString(message);
}
```

Now, when I try to send a GCM message with this function (trying to send multiple message in one request. So I have a JsonArray like this (gcm json message):

```
<message id="lT2FX-2"><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{"to":["APA91bGnOTbGWmIW6Bjq_derdLpLbdYo90eLdls7miIrBXSWPyKlWU7y_Dnp2y1AE41bdkQYo70egwi-QnRDzGPxeABvygLmiukLN5ZfcxfXq-D8ekDb1KaiJOsHHPH1bq5HOq9K4wWUDVYmWzAtMwfWUR5YEUUKDw","APA91bHTe_PMWa3xsqIlYebmNCeVaF7FbqtZ-QC4WxKltMnyDFIBakjr8TfWrL2cQr47XWxev4f13Mdjk-5LVTiFZ13hv1duGhib00skO2zmCoyAKQGETI7ECB6suMG9lFyAUW6_PfUiCS4eOvlshscdF6ztu80pkw","APA91bHj5cWhbnGmQ5h20Hx93JQeo5ejq3iJcY_fBNwxhPnSkvgRYRNbFzSzSgwXJDBDcb97CgvDfQukYAuFpCWj1-4d7CGWiD7sGkXyNheQuKhVbuTFKg32VdJNazrCT7-XX7GAOYxhEe-E9U-XoZmQ6N6FNua4wg"],"collapse_key":"newGreenStatus","data": ...
```

This is not working, but when I switch back to a single registration id (something like this:

```
<message id="cXEMp-2"><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{"to":"APA91bHj5cWhbnGmQ5h20Hx93JQeo5ejq3iJcY_fBNwxhPnSkvgRYRNbFzSzSgwXJDBDcb97CgvDfQukYAuFpCWj1-4d7CGWiD7sGkXyNheQuKhVbuTFKg32VdJNazrCT7-XX7GAOYxhEe-E9U-XoZmQ6N6FNua4wg","collapse_key":"newGreenStatus","data":
```

then it's working again.

I also tried changing "to" to "registration_ids" and still no changes. (Of course the parameter in `createJsonMessage` is changed back to String.)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to the problem here: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html

In CCS

> CCS does not support multicast messaging.

So, it is not possible...